# windows 7 performance with java

Tags: windows-7

im thinking on updrading from vista to windows 7.
i mainly progam in java for my university projects and thesis on computer science. i often use a linux partition with debian.

my question is about how had been you experience programming on windows 7? is it faster? does it have full compatibility, eetc. what about de IDEs?

windows 7 professional costs a lot of money in my country so i need to make a good choice.

ahhh i forgot. im using a dell vostro 1320  Core2 Duo T6670 2.2GHz with 3gb of ram, is that enough for win 7?

thanks a lot in advance!

diego

Answer (score 1):

Compatibility and performance in general are on par with Windows Vista, regardless of whether you choose Java or anything else.

Generally you can expect Java to work. I haven't had any problems with it so far, not even in the beta and RC. Eclipse does run, too.

The approximately-native-looking Swing PLAF looks a little wonky with Aero but that has always been that way with Java, even on Vista.

Answer (score 0):

This is all subjective but I haven't had a problem using Win7 and eclipse 3.5.  The real question is, is your box up to snuff.

Comment: It runs Vista at the moment, according to the OP. The requirements and performance are pretty much identical.